# changing background color of ListView disables highlight color

Tags: android, onclick, listactivity

I've got a list of search results which are being shown in a ListActivity. When I change the background color of the ListActivity items, by changing the background color of the first LinearLayout (parent), the OnClick highlight stops working. Why is this and how can I make this highlight still work when I change the background color of my items? On a side note, is it possible to change the color of this highlight? Thanks.

My XML is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout>
 <ImageView>
 <LinearLayout>
  <TextView>
  </TextView>
  <TextView>
  </TextView>
  <TextView>
  </TextView>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity is like this:

```
public class ResultsPage extends ListActivity {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of the way that Android handles backgrounds.  The default background for a ListView is a selector drawable defined in XML which specifies different backgrounds for different states.  When you tell a ListView to have a specific background image or color then you've lost the selector that told it what to do in different states.

See the section 'State List' here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

And, to answer your second question, yes.  If you want to change the highlight background just do so as specified in the documentation on that page above.  You can define your own drawables as state lists with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction mate. This is going to be harder than I thought but I need to tackle this.

Answer (score 5):

As James says, if you change your background color in your code, when the user select an item in the ListView at execution time, it doesn't highlights the item.

You can fix these behavior, using the attribute drawSelectorOnTop="true" in your ListView definition. For example

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
/>
```

Comment: This works, but then the highlighted background would go over any textview or image you have.

Comment: I have been dealing with this problem for days and hours. I was trying to have the ripple effect with a specific background. When I had a background, the ripple effect was disappearing. Now I have both the custom background for the items and the ripple effect. Thank you very much.